# Getting Permission Denied while trying to connect to Azure DEV Ops Using SSH Key

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, ssh-keys

I have created a public private key pair in my machine. I have put the public key in Azure DevOps by going to "SSH Public Keys" from top right beside my avatar

So now from the command prompt when i try :

ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com , i see the below thing

I have put in the correct password, but still facing this below

```
$ ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
The authenticity of host 'ssh.dev.azure.com (52.228.82.0)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ohD8VZEXGWo6Ez8GSEJQ9WpafgLFsOfLOtGGQCQo6Og.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ssh.dev.azure.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
```